# How to query ManyToManyField to get the attribute from another model

Tags: python, database, sqlite, django-models

Here is my Model_Items:

```
class Model_Items(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
    make = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    model = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
```

Which the Po has a ManyToMany relationship with:

```
class Po(models.Model):
    po_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
    receive_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, default='')
    model_item = models.ManyToManyField(Model_Items)
    site_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=50, default='')
```

Now in my View I query it :

```
def po_page(request, *args, **kwargs):
    po = Po.objects.all()

    context = {
        'po_list': po,
    }
    return render(request, 'po/po_page.html', context)
```

On my Template:

```
{% for my_po_list in po_list %}
    <div class="card">
        <table class="table table-bordered" >
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-2">{{ my_po_list.po_number }}</td>
                <td class="col-md-2">{{ my_po_list.receive_date }}</td>
                <td class="col-md-2">{{ my_po_list.model_item.all }}</td>
                <td class="col-md-2">{{ my_po_list.site_code }}</td>
                <td class="col-md-2">{{ my_po_list.comment }}</td>
                <td class="col-md-2">{{ model }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I have been struggling to get get  title from Model_Items class and displaying it.
However the line with:

```
{{ my_po_list.model_item.all }}
```

Displays the following instead
`<QuerySet [<Model_Items: Mac 16 Dev>, <Model_Items: Mac 13 Std>]>`.

I know the line is suppose to do that but how can I filter it so it just displays the Model_Items title.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a for loop to loop through the model items. I also added in what you would do to add commas between the titles.

```
<td class="col-md-2">
    {% for model_item in my_po_list.model_item.all %}
        {{model_item. title}}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</td>
```